# Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, sums-of-squares

$(x_{1},x_{2}, \cdots ,x_{n})$ is sample of size $n$ from population with normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(m,2)$.

What kind of distribution does the statistic $\dfrac{\sum \left(x_{i}- \bar{x}\right)^2}{ 2}$ have?

How do I solve these kind of questions?

What I know is that the average of variables with $\mathcal{N}(m,\sigma^2)$ has $\mathcal{N}(m,\sigma^2/n)$. I guess $\sum x_{i}^2$ has chi-square distribution but I can't solve for this combination. Any help?

Comment: I assume 'average' is the sample mean. Then it follows the chi-square distribution with (n-1) degrees of freedom. Try to recall the relation between the normal and chi-square. The proof requires a fair amount of math so I'm not writing it here.

Comment: @DaeyoungLim  just to check my solution.    If   X~N(m,2)  then                 Y=(X-m)/sqrt(2) has N(0,1) . Then Y^2=(X-m)^2/2 has chi-square distribution with 1 degree of freedom. Then ∑(X-m)^2/2 has chi-squared distribution with n degrees of freedom. Since μ^=x¯ we lose one degree of freedom and finaly  ∑(X-x¯)^2/2 has chi-square distribution with (n-1) degrees of freedom

Comment: yes, that's correct. You could also generalize the variance to $\sigma^{2}$ instead of 2 and the same result applies.

Comment: @ToneyS The numerator in your [edit](http://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/91629d7b-150b-459a-922e-8bcc93d8048c/view-source) of the formula is wrong - it should have parentheses, so you're squaring the difference rather than just the $\bar x$ term, as the original post did.

Comment: If by "these kind of questions" you mean those related to quadratic functions of Normal random variables, please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+quadratic+form.

Comment: @DaeyoungLim Should you perhaps make your comment into an answer?  I am new to the site so not sure if I understand the appropriate etiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n}$ follow independent and identically distributed $\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$, then each $Y_{i}^{2}$ follows a chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom which leads to the result that $\sum_{i}Y_{i}$ follows $\chi^{2}\left(n\right)$.

In your case, $X_{1},\ldots, X_{n}$ follows independent and identically distributed $\mathcal{N}\left(m,2\right)$. To apply the above, we need to transform them into standard normal variables and we all know how: standardize. That's where we get to $2^{-1/2}\left(X_{i}-m\right)\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$. Square it so that it follows a chi-squared distribution:
$$
\dfrac{\left(X_{i}-m\right)^{2}}{2}\sim \chi^{2}\left(1\right), \qquad \sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\left(X_{i}-m\right)^{2}}{2}\sim \chi^{2}\left(n\right)
$$
If we could do without mathematical rigour, then let's just proceed by simply stating that all the deviations $X_{i}-\overline{X}_{n}$ are independent. So we can obtain the same result except that we lose one degree of freedom because we've estimated the mean $m$ with $\overline{X}_{n}$ in advance.
$$
\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\overline{X}_{n}\right)^{2}\sim \chi^{2}\left(n-1\right)
$$

Comment: The deviations clearly are not independent, because they sum to zero.